# Using functions from other files in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm  making a game in JS using P5, and I came upon a problem.

In my html file I have references to .js files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.3/p5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <script src="isKeyPressed.js"></script>
  <script src="blocks.js"></script>
  <script src="player.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I have one .js file defining the function isKeyPressed():

```
function isKeyPressed(keyQuery) {
  var did = false;
  for(var i = 0; i < keysPressed; i++) {
    if(keysPressed[i] === keyQuery) {
      did = true;
    }
  }
  return did;
}
```

I reference this in another object inside player.js:

```
player.motion = function() {
  if(isKeyPressed('w')) {
    this.velocity.add(0,-5);
  }
  if(isKeyPressed('s')) {
    this.velocity.add(0,5);
  }
  if(isKeyPressed('a')) {
    this.velocity.add(-5,0);
  }
  if(isKeyPressed('d')) {
    this.velocity.add(5,0);
  }
}
```

But when I try to call player.motion, I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: isKeyPressed is not a function

Does anyone know why this is occurring?

Comment: Either the file is not loaded or the function is not in global scope.

Comment: If it is defined in a global scope in a file that was loaded prior to `player.js` - it would work.

Comment: Not what you're asking, but why would you put that function in a file by itself when it doesn't work without the `keysPressed` variable that is apparently defined elsewhere? Also, your `for` condition is missing `.length` from `keysPressed`, but I suggest you use an object rather than an array to track which keys are pressed, because then you don't need to mess around with loops, you can just test for a key directly.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a website running this code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.3/p5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <script src="isKeyPressed.js"></script>
  <script src="blocks.js"></script>
  <script src="player.js"></script>
  <script>
    player.motion = function() {
      if(isKeyPressed('w')) {
        this.velocity.add(0,-5);
      }
      if(isKeyPressed('s')) {
        this.velocity.add(0,5);
      }
      if(isKeyPressed('a')) {
        this.velocity.add(-5,0);
      }
      if(isKeyPressed('d')) {
        this.velocity.add(5,0);
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This is importing all functions from the `isKeyPressed.js` file and therefore you are able to reference it in the `<script>` tag. You were not able to use `isKeyPressed.js`'s functions in `player.js` because you cannot reference it.

Comment: Why was the OP not able to access `isKeyPressed()` in the `player.js` file?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Because the file `isKeyPressed.js` was in was not loaded to `player.js`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that. The `isKeyPressed.js` file was loaded before `player.js`. What am I missing?

Comment: @KevinWorkman `isKeyPressed.js` was loaded to the CLIENT, not `player.js`.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Maybe you would like to ask a separate question?

Comment: I wouldn't even know what to ask. I just don't understand what you're saying. When I use Bootstrap, it requires JQuery. Code in `bootstrap.js` uses functions defined in `jquery.js` just fine. I don't understand how OP's situation is much different from that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123379/discussion-between-bjskistad-and-kevin-workman).

Answer (score 2):

For the record, I don't think the accepted answer is correct. Specifically, I don't think the accepted answer really changes anything from what you were originally doing. My guess is that you had another problem in your code (like a syntax error) that was causing this error, and you fixed that in the process of implementing the suggested solution. So while it might look like the solution fixed your problem, really it was something else.

I'm providing this alternative answer so you don't think you have to define your JavaScript in your html directly, as that is definitely not the case.

I tried testing out your setup by creating a smaller example consisting of three files:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="one.js"></script>
  <script src="two.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="printObj()">
</body>
</html>
```

**one.js**

```
function printOne(){
    console.log("one");
}
```

**two.js**

```
var obj = {};

obj.printTwo = function(){
    console.log("two");
    printOne();
}

function printObj(){
    obj.printTwo();
}
```

This is pretty much exactly what your setup is, and **it works fine.** You absolutely **do not** need to put your JavaScript in your html. As long as the JavaScript files are **correctly loaded** in the **proper order**, then you can use functions and variables from one file in another file.

There are two main things that could cause your problem:

**Are your files correctly loaded?**

- Are there any syntax errors you haven't noticed? **(This is my guess as to what caused your original problem.)** Check the JavaScript console, and try running some test code to actually run the functions you're trying to call.
- Did you get all the file names correct?
- Are you behind a firewall, or are there other network problems that might cause a problem with loading?

**Are your files loaded in the proper order?**

- For file `two.js` to access code defined in `one.js`, you have to make sure `one.js` is loaded before `two.js`. It looks like you've done this correctly, but are you sure the JavaScript is where you think it is?
- In other words, **are you sure it was in `player.js` and not in `main.js`?**
- You might want to get rid of this ambiguity by placing related JavaScript in the same file. It doesn't make a ton of sense to have one file define a `keysPressed` array and then another file use that array to define an `isKeyPressed()` function. Just put them in the same file, and make sure that file is loaded before other files that use it.

**The accepted answer doesn't change anything with regard to when stuff is loaded.** Unless you had a syntax error, or the `player.motion()` function was actually in the `main.js` file, or you had a network loading problem, your code should have worked. So one of those things must be your actual problem. **You do not have to define your JavaScript in your html for it to work.**

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not making a file name have capitals. So change it from

```
<script src="isKeyPressed.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="iskeypressed.js"></script>
```

also change the file name too.